# OpenLayers Map breaks when open developer tools or download something

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

im using Openlayers 3 for a while, and i keep this problem.

When im using Chrome, and open the developer tools or closing it, my OpenLayers Map moves such a bit, the same goes when i download something. Of course this does not make bigger problems, but one of the functions in my map is to make zoom by bounce, and if the map is moved like i said the bounce does not go to the right place, it goes a little close.

This is an image before opening the developers tool:
[before opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imwUC.jpg)

And this is an image after opening the developers tool:
[after opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfFB8.jpg)

Hope someone can help, if need more details just tell.
Thanks!

Comment: Hard to provide answers without a being able to replicate the problem, does using developer tools change your window size?

Comment: Yes, its like the developers tool pushes de map instead of being placed hover it. The same goes to the download bar in the bottom of the web navigator, it pushes the map up, and when i close it (one or both of them) the map resize it to the full width-height size of the navigator, but something has change, like the images. Thanks for help

Comment: I have founded also that anytime i move de web navegator window size, the map center moves a bit.

Comment: it's weird. map center shouldn't be moved though view size is changed